# Confused by memory allocation and garbage collection in Julia

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, julia

I am a bit confused by memory allocation in Julia. I [know from the FAQ](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/faq/) that clearing the memory used by a large variable is done by setting it to something small (like 0) and then running `gc()`.

However, I'm a bit confused by the following. I create a random `Float32` array:

```
@time A = rand(Float32, 10000, 10000);
```

`time` indicates that ~400MB of RAM was allocated, and Julia's RAM usage increases by 400MB. This makes sense.

I then apply `fft`, but don't bind the result to any variable:

```
@time fft(A);
```

`time` indicates that ~800MB of RAM was allocated, and Julia's RAM usage increases by 800MB.

*However*, the RAM usage remains at 1.2GB higher than at the start. And that confuses me, because I didn't equate any variable to `fft(A)`, so I would expect that the 800MB allocated would be immediately freed after the `fft` was executed.

I tried to run `gc`, thinking that Julia would realize that there was an additional 800MB of RAM that was being used for nothing:

```
gc();
```

This does nothing. RAM usage remains at ~1.3GB.

However, the following two lines,

```
A = 0;
gc();
```

frees all 1.2GB that is in use, despite the fact that `sizeof(A)` is only 400MB. So my question is:

- Why does it appear as though an object which is 400MB in size (according to `sizeof`) actually has 1.2GB allocated to it?

Comment: Have a look at `whos()` between each command.  `ans` takes some room.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Oh, so data gets allocated to `ans`, *even if the command is terminated by a semicolon*? Wow, ok, that makes sense, although it seems counter-intuitive to a beginner like me. Mind putting that up as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Semicolon is just to suppress output, as in MATLAB (which inspired it). I don't think this case you've hit on here comes up much because one normally allocates results to something, but it is interesting.

Comment: @IainDunning: One more question: if I do `A = rand(Float32, 10000, 10000);` and then do `A = fft(A);`, my memory usage still appears as though both the original real array and the resulting complex array are in memory. However, calling `whos()` shows that both `A` and `ans` are memory pointers to the same complex array. Executing `ans = 1` does not free the unused memory, but explicitly calling `gc()` does. Is that the intended behavior (ie, Julia does not automatically garbage-collect variables which have been overwritten by something else)?

Comment: Garbage collection will only happen when it is needed, or explicitly called. There is no guarantee of when garbage collection will take place as far as I know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each command returns something, even if it is only `nothing`.  `ans` is assigned to each returned object even if there is no direct assignment and even if the command ends with a semicolon.

** **EDIT** ** [Updated info for Julia version ≥ v0.7.0]

Use `varinfo()` for Julia v0.7.0 and higher (`whos()` for Julia v0.6.4 and lower) between commands to watch assignments and the allocated space.

Answer (score 1):

`whos` has been replaced with `varinfo()` in [Julia 0.7](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.7.0/NEWS/), discussion [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12131).