# Julia: garbage collection inside functions works differently than in global space

Tags: garbage-collection, julia

I have yet another question about garbage collection in Julia. Here is a minimal example:

```
function OscarTheGrouch()
    A = rand(Float32, 20000, 20000);
    A = 0;
    gc();
end
```

Calling `OscarTheGrouch()` causes RAM use to increase by 1.6GB. Calling `gc()` afterwards causes it to drop by 1.6GB.

In contrast, simply executing the code inside the function in the global scope, ie, executing

```
A = rand(Float32, 20000, 20000);
A = 0;
gc();
```

leaves RAM use unchanged before and after execution.

[My previous RAM use question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728040/confused-by-memory-allocation-and-garbage-collection-in-julia) turned out to simply be due to the fact that intermediate results are stored as `ans`. However, calling `whos()` after calling `OscarTheGrouch()` shows no intermediate array results being stored.

- So, where is the memory being held? Does garbage collection inside functions behave differently (less aggressively?) than in the global scope?

I skimmed the [article on Julia functions](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/), but didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: Many things are different in the global scope, for sure - the compiler is able to infer less. I don't think is one of them.

Comment: Posted as an issue at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8393

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce your behaviour

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.0 (2014-08-20 20:43 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0

julia> # Memory now about 64M

julia> A = rand(Float32, 20000, 20000);

julia> # Memory now about 1600M

julia> A = 0
0
julia> gc()

julia> # Memory now about 75M

julia> function test1()
         A = rand(Float32, 20000, 20000)
         nothing
       end
test1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test1()  # Still about 78, although briefly higher

julia> function test2()
         A = rand(Float32, 20000, 20000)
         A = 0
       end
test2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test2()  # Same behaviour
0

julia> function test3()
           A = rand(Float32, 20000, 20000)
           A = 0
           gc()
       end
test3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test3()  # Now at 1600M
```

Comment: I think that's what @DumpsterDoofus sees, too.  The issue is that a `gc()` call compiled into a function doesn't seem to collect unreachable arrays allocated within that same function — which I can reproduce.  Even stranger, it seems like the `gc()` call in `OscarTheGrouch()` is *preventing* collection!

Comment: Yeah, as Matt B. says, I think there's a bit of a misunderstanding: I'm getting exactly the same result as you do when I execute what you did (ie, executing the code in the global scope), and that's perfectly normal. However, try to execute `OscarTheGrouch` instead, and see what happens! My point is that when code is wrapped inside of a function and the function is executed, garbage collection does not work properly.

Comment: Ah I see, I have now recreated it, that is subtle. This is appropriate for a Github Issue on Julia, not a SO question. I'm not sure who downvoted me, but, not cool.

Comment: @IainDunning: Thanks, I'll post it on GitHub as a possible bug if you haven't already. Dunno who downvoted you, it wasn't me.